# JDBC VS Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

We have been using JDBC for a very long time in our web applications. The main reason we used it is because we have 100% control over the code, sql and fix things by our hands. Apart from that we used triggers inside the database, and the database is developed separately by DB experts.

However many now recommend using `Hibernate` so we also thought about using it. But, we found the below issues.

1. Hibernate cannot connect with an "Existing" database. It always try to create a one of its own.
2. Our database might access by same application which is in different platforms (cloud, server, VPS, Personal Computer). Hibernate can make problems because of its caching in this situation.
3. We never like to give the "table creating work" to the java code. We create tables manually, always.
4. We might have to use very long and complex SQL statements. Last time we used an statement with more than 150 lines, joining more than 20 tables. We doubt whether we will face troubles in this when it comes to Hibernate.
5. Our SQL code is nice and standard. Hibernate generated code seems to be bit dirty for us.
6. We always use MySQL. Never use any other DB.
7. The application we create require max security, related to medical. If at least one data record is leaked, we are done.
8. There are lot of `foreign keys`, `Primary Keys`, `Composite Keys`, `Unique Keys` etc etc in database. In forums, some complained that Hibernate messed with those.
9. We decided to try hibernate because some people claims, "Are you Software Engineers? You are using already dead `JDBC` !!. "

Considering these, please let me know whether the above points are actually true (as I said, I got to know them via googling, discussion etc) or not. And, what are the pros and cons of Hibernate VS Java JDBC?

Comment: 1+3: You don't have to let Hibernate create the tables for you. 2: You don't have to use caching. 4+5: I get that. Maybe you want to look at jOOQ. Typesafe Java DSL for handwritten SQL, without getting into ORM. 6: Hibernate supports MySQL. 7: That seems to be a completely separate issue (has nothing to do with what database access library you use)

Comment: @Alex: Thanks for the reply. I added 2 more points, pls take a look.

Comment: @Thilo: Thanks for the comment. I added 2 more points, please take a look.

Comment: Obviously it ISN'T a question of JDBC or Hibernate. It is JDBC or JPA. You know, some JPA implementations do things differently to Hibernate. Perhaps open your options to other things out there ...

Answer (score 31):

Answering issues listed above:

*1. Hibernate cannot connect with an "Existing" database. It always try to create a one of its own.*

This is wrong. Hibernate **can** connect to an existing database, and it doesn't always try to recreate it. You just should turn of parameter like `hbm2ddl. auto`.

*2. Our database might access by same application which is in different platforms (cloud, server, VPS, Personal Computer). Hibernate can make problems because of its caching in this situation.*

Hibernate has an adjustable cache, so this is also not a problem.

*3. We never like to give the "table creating work" to the java code. We create tables manually, always.*

No problem. See p.1 above. Furthemore there are several convinient libraries for indirect table creation and update (e.g. [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)) which can be used in couple with hibernate perfectly.

*4. We might have to use very long and complex SQL statements. Last time we used an statement with more than 150 lines, joining more than 20 tables. We doubt whether we will face troubles in this when it comes to Hibernate.*

You can always use direct JDBC calls and invoke native SQL queries via hibernate, if it is neeeded.

*5. Our SQL code is nice and standard. Hibernate generated code seems to be bit dirty for us.*

Again, if you have to invoke some logic complicated SQL code instead of hibernate auto-generated - you can do it.

*6. We always use MySQL. Never use any other DB.*

Not a problem at all. Hibernate has special MySQL dialect support: `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`.

*7. The application we create require max security, related to medical. If at least one data record is leaked, we are done.*

Security issues aren't related to ORM techniques. `Hibernate` is just logical and convinient object-oriented layer between pure database JDBC calls and programmers tools. It doesn't influence somehow on common net security.

Answer (score 19):

Hibernate is a great tool and you'll find plenty of [documentation](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/), books, and blog articles about it.

I will address all your concerns:

> Hibernate cannot connect with an "Existing" database. It always tries to create one of its own.

Hibernate should use a separate database schema management procedure even for integration testing. You should use an incremental versioning tool like [FlywayDB](http://flywaydb.org/) to manage your schema changes.

> Our database might access by same application which is in different platforms (cloud, server, VPS, Personal Computer). Hibernate can make problems because of its caching in this situation.

You don't have to use the 2nd level cache, which uses 3rd party caching implementations. All caching solutions may break transactional consistency. The first level cache guarantees session-level repeatable reads and with the optimistic locking in place you can prevent [lost updates](http://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/).

> We never like to give the "table creating work" to the java code. We create tables manually, always.

The DB should be separated from your ORM tool. That's a best practice anyway.

> We might have to use very long and complex SQL statements. Last time we used an statement with more than 150 lines, joining more than 20 tables. We doubt whether we will face troubles in this when it comes to Hibernate.

Hibernate is great for write operations and for concurrency control. You still need to use native SQL for advanced queries (window functions, CTE). But Hibernate allows you to run native queries.

> Our SQL code is nice and standard. Hibernate generated code seems to be bit dirty for us.

You don't need and you shouldn't probably use the hbmdll utility anyway.

> We always use MySQL. Never use any other DB.

That's even better. You can therefore use advance native queries without caring for database portability issues.

> The application we create require max security, related to medical. If at least one data record is leaked, we are done.

Hibernate doesn't prevent you from securing your database or the data access code. You can still use database security measures with Hibernate too. You can even use [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) to enable all sorts of security-related features:

- advanced password hashing
- two-way encryption

> There are lot of foreign keys, Primary Keys, Composite Keys, Unique Keys etc etc in database. In forums, some complained that Hibernate messed with those.

All of those are supported by Hibernate. Aside from the JPA conventions, Hibernate also offers [particular mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/) for any exotic mapping.

> We decided to try hibernate because some people claims, "Are you Software Engineers? You are using already dead JDBC !!. "

That's not the right argument for switching from a library you already master. If you think you can benefit from using Hibernate then that's the only compelling reason for switching from JDBC.

Answer (score 3):

Using plain old JDBC, does not mean you are lacking in IT industry, rather Hibernate also uses JDBC in the underlying layer.

What advantages it gives us what we should look for.

1.) `Cache` Mechanism.

2.) Managing `sessions`, `transactions` etc.

3.) Reduce efforts in writing queries, more utilities of hibernate like `Query API`, `Criteria API`, `HQL`

The questions that you have raised are more or less covered in [Hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/).

Also there are lot more caching strategy available ehcache, infinispan, depends on the server we are deploying, JBOSS, Weblogic, Tomcat etc. ++ environment like cloud, distributed cache etc.

Hibernate still provides you with option of turning off automatically creating schema and pointing to the one create by you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the quick answers that I know

1) You can connect to an existing database. But yeah as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227098/using-hibernate-for-existing-database)

> If you don't have a solid object model, I'd say that Hibernate is a
>   terrible choice.

2) As you database is been accessed from different applications so you can maintain locks. On-the-other-hand you can **trun-off** caching as done [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/TurnoffCacheThroughConfigFile.htm).

3) You can create tables manually and connect it using `.hbm.xml` file.

4) You can use any type of query in hibernate like simple SQL queries criteria.

5) You can directly use SQL code in Hibernate, if you want. Other option is to use criteria.

6) Hibernate is NOT DB specific. You can go for any Database and connect it with hibernate.

7) Using locks and giving rights in database you can maintain security.

8) Agreed that foreign keys are messy in Hibernate **If You Donot Handle It Well**. So Use OO approach and maintain cascades well, then Hibernate will be good choice.

Comment: what did you mean by `solid object model` ?

Comment: By `solid object model` I mean that you maps the database on JAVA files Object Oriented way i.e. to have maintain relationship and maps the foreign keys in OO way.